# I was trying to make canActivated guard with promise for my application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I have a separate service file called `auth.service.ts` file which have promise that returns the `loggedIn` value as true or false.

I have used a `canActivate` method in separate `auth.service.ts` file which uses the promise and `loggedIn` value using of type boolean. But, it displays error if I mention it as boolean and even not mentioning anything and also given as any.

`auth-guard.service.ts` file:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree  } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";


@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {


    constructor( private authService : AuthService , private router : Router){}
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):
 boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree | any > {
    
 return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
        .then(
            (authenticated: boolean) => {
                if (authenticated) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    this.router.navigate(['/']);
                }
            }
        );
        
    }
}
```

`auth.service.ts` file:

```
export class AuthService {
    loggedIn : boolean = false ;

isAuthenticated(){
    const promise = new Promise(
        (resolve,reject) => {
            setTimeout(
                () => {
                    resolve(this.loggedIn);
                },800);
        }
    );
    return promise;
}


login(){
    this.loggedIn = true ;
}

logout(){
    this.loggedIn = false ;
}

}
```

Error facing:

```
Error: src/app/auth-guard.service.ts:17:13 - error TS2345: Argument of type '(authenticated: boolean) => true | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown) => true | PromiseLike<true | undefined> | undefined'.
  Types of parameters 'authenticated' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

17             (authenticated: boolean) => {
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/auth-guard.service.ts:17:13 - error TS7030: Not all code paths return a value.

17             (authenticated: boolean) => {
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~




× Failed to compile.
```

Comment: In your `else` block, you're not returning anything so the error message seems to be correct. Add a `return false`.

Answer (score 0):

after this.router.navigate(['/']) you have to add return false;

Comment: Thank you for your response . But , it is not working .

Answer (score 0):

Add error handler inside then and return in else:

```
 return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
    .then(
        (authenticated: boolean) => {
            if (authenticated) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
               return this.router.navigate(['/']);
            }
        },
        err=> this.router.navigate(['/']
    );
    
}
```